# Solving integer equation with an oddness (or related) constraint

Tags: equation-solving

Consider this problem:

Find all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\{ x,y \} \leq 100$, $y$ is odd, and

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{y} = \frac{1}{12} .$$

One can convert the condition on $y$ to be $y = 2 z + 1$ for $0 \leq z \leq 49$ and get the answer indirectly:

```
Solve[{0 <= x <= 100, 0 <= z <= 49,
  1/x + 4/(2 z + 1) == 1/12},{x,z},
Integers]
```

{{x -> 76, z -> 28}}

and then convert $z$ back to find $y$.  (There is a unique solution given the constraint.)

My question, though, is how to solve the equation directly with that oddness constraint.  The obvious approach:

```
Solve[{0<x<=100, 0<=y<=100, OddQ[y],
  1/x + 4/y == 1/12},{x,y},
Integers]
```

and straightforward variations do not work.

The closest I could get was

```
Assuming[OddQ[y],
Solve[{0<x<=100, 0<=y<=100,
  1/x + 4/y == 1/12},{x,y},
Integers
]]
```

which gives *many* answers plus a warning that some of the solutions do not obey the assumption.  (Indeed, all but one of the solutions so violate the assumption.)

I hope there is a direct method, not one which relies on numerous intermediate solutions, of which I computationally select the one(s) that satisfy the constraint.

This works, but is not quite what I seek:

```
Solve[{0<x<=100, 0<=y<=100,Mod[y,2]==1,
  1/x + 4/y == 1/12},{x,y},
Integers
]
```

My full question involves several such constraints, e.g., some variables are even, some variables are odd...

Comment: ```FindInstance[
 1/x + 4/y == 1/12 && Mod[y, 2] == 1 && x <= 100 && y <= 100, {x, 
  y}, PositiveIntegers, 10^10]``` You can't use `OddQ` and must use `Mod` because 'Q' style functions don't work with symbolic arguments like that e.g `OddQ[y]` is `False` if y is a symbol with no value.

Comment: In your `Assuming[OddQ[y],...` above, for the reasons I stated, this is first changed to `Assuming[False,...` which would explain the warnings.

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides:  Thanks.  The constraints I will impose in my true problem are generated elsewhere and come in long lists of `OddQ`, `EvenQ`, `PositiveQ`, and conjunctions and disjunctions thereof.  I suppose I *could* try to express all these in standard equation form, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @flinty:  Thanks, but `FindInstance` isn't quite right because my full (large) equation may have multiple solutions (obeying the constraints).  Your explanation about how OddQ won't work with symbolic arguments is a big help...  thanks for that insight.

Comment: `FindInstance` returns multiple solutions so I don't see why that's a problem  (see the last argument). You cannot use 'Q' functions. Another way to express without using `Mod` is `FractionalPart[y/2] > 0` but that's just more long winded.

Comment: @flinty:  I guess you're right.  `FindInstance` with a limit of $10^{10}$ works, though seems inelegant.  But given that I now see `OddQ` can't be "computed" as I hoped, these may be the only solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  Admittedly, would like to understand better why this works, and surely there must be a more elegent way.

```
p = Solve[{0 < x <= 100, 0 <= y <= 100, 1/x + 4/y == 1/12}, {x, y}, Integers];
q = OddQ[y /. p];
p[[Flatten[Position[q, True]]]]
```

Comment: Weird and inelegant... but helpful ($+1$).  It would be truly ugly in my full problem where my constraints are of the form `OddQ[y] OR (EvenQ[x] AND NonNegative[y])`...

Comment: This is just filtering out the odd $y$ solutions. You could do both those lines in a single `Select[p, OddQ[y /. #] &]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork,  Hahaha,  LoL. Glad it was (somewhat) helpful.

Comment: @flinty, that is exactly what I was trying to do, but did not have the necessary vocabulary.  Anyway, seems that it is easier for *Mathematica* to filter out some types of constraints rather than embed them in the problem statement.